# wireless troubles with Intel 3945ABG

Tags: wireless, intel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wireless doesn't work on an HP Pavillion DV6000 with an Intel 3945abg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88129/wireless-doesnt-work-on-an-hp-pavillion-dv6000-with-an-intel-3945abg)

Please Help! I cannot connect to wireless it shows my connection i enter password and yes its the right one im sure of it then it trys to connect and cannot. then about 30 second or so later it trys again automatically. ive looked at other forums and ive tried everything nothing works. Also i submitted this a few days ago but no answers but i have more information can someone please help

[Here's What i get from the Terminal](http://pastebin.com/ENjxRd71).

[Here's New Information After uninstall and reinstall](http://pastebin.com/TJ9rskvw).